# How to change the primary color of the Flutter Material 3 DatePicker?

Tags: flutter, material-design

I am using showDatePicker() to display a Datepicker in my Flutter App.

**How can I change the purple color?**

Here is my Theme so far:

```html
DatePickerThemeData(
  backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 38, 41, 48),
  surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,
  headerForegroundColor: Colors.white,
                  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
DatePickerThemeData(
            backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 38, 41, 48),
            surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,
            headerForegroundColor: Colors.white,

            //u need to match the text color also
            dayBackgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
              if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
                return Colors.green;
              }
              return Colors.black;
            }),)
```

Comment: background is bg, foreground is for text, and to change all you need to change `todayBackgroundColor` too

Comment: That worked for me! Also any idea how I can change the color of the border of the input field, where I can change the date by keyboard in the datepicker widget?

Comment: try `inputDecorationTheme`, if its null it will use general `InputDecorationTheme` in main Theme Data instead

Comment: This did not work:
 inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
                    border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)))

Comment: `InputDecorationTheme(focusedBorder: , enableBorder: ,)` , please try both of field. give me update if its not work either.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated:** Changes in UI.

Here's your solution. Feel free to provide acknowledgement in the comment section.

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: "My App",
      home: NewHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class NewHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<NewHomePage> createState() => _NewHomePageState();
}

class _NewHomePageState extends State<NewHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: openDatePicker,
          child: const Text("Open Date Picker"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> openDatePicker() async {
    await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(2000),
      lastDate: DateTime(3000),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        return Theme(
          // The below-written code will only affect the pop-up window.
          data: ThemeData(
            // I tried to match my picker with your photo.
            useMaterial3: true,
            brightness: Brightness.dark,
            colorSchemeSeed: Colors.purple,
            // Write your own code for customizing the date picker theme.
            datePickerTheme: const DatePickerThemeData(),
          ),
          child: child ?? const SizedBox(),
        );
      },
    );
    return Future<void>.value();
  }
}
```

Comment: This brings the same result I already had with my global theme. How can I change the purple color of the selected Date?

Comment: I update my answer. Check it out.